# how to parse elements of a list of dictionary in django template(index.html) using for loop

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

**`models.py`**

```
class Data(models.Model):
    price = models.CharField(max_length=264,unique=False,blank=True,null=True)
    shipping = models.CharField(max_length=264,unique=False,blank=True,null=True)
    netprice = models.CharField(max_length=264,unique=False,blank=True,null=True)
    points = models.CharField(max_length=264,unique=False,blank=True,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.price)
```

**`views.py`**

```
def index(request):
  az_list=list(Data.objects.all())
  return render(request,{'az_list':az_list,'loop':range(500)})
```

**`index.html`**

```
{% for i in loop %}
  {{ az_list.i.price}}
  {{ az_list.i.shipping}}
  {{ az_list.i.netprice}}
  {{ az_list.i.points}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Why donm't you loop *directly* over the `az_list`? You can not obtain the `i`-th index of an element in Django templates (at least not without a template filter or template tag).

Comment: this is snippet one i have 4 lists like az_list,ay_list,ax_list,ap_list and they are in table so they need to itterated in one loop

Comment: then you need to use a `zip(..)`.

Comment: then please explain how could i parse the elements

Comment: thank you so much it worked !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Django template, you can not easily obtain the *i*-th element of a list, not without a template filter, or a template tag. Furthermore it is bad design. The Pythonic way to iterate over a list is, well, iterate over the list. You can thus write it like:

```
{% for element in az_list %}
  {{ element.price}}
  {{ element.shipping}}
  {{ element.netprice}}
  {{ element.points}}
{% endfor %}
```

If you want to *limit* the nuber of elements you want to render, you can do so by setting a limit in the query, like:

```
def index(request):
  az_list = Data.objects.all()[:500]
  return render(request, 'template.html', {'az_list': az_list})
```

This will also boost performance, since now you are fetching only at most 500 records from the database, and not first fetch *all* records, and then render only the first 500.

**EDIT**: in case you want to *concurrently* iterate over multiple iterables, you can use a `zip(..)`. For example:

```
def index(request):
    ax_list = Model1.objects.all()
    ay_list = Model2.objects.all()
    az_list = Model3.objects.all()
    return render(
        request,
        'template.html',
        {'all_data': zip(ax_list, az_list)}
    )
```

and then we can iterate over the elements like:

```
{% for axi, ayi, azi in all_data %}
  {{ axi.price}}
  {{ axi.shipping}}
  {{ axi.netprice}}
  {{ axi.points}}
{% endfor %}
```

Here the `axi`, `ayi` and `azi` are the elements in the three lists, at the *same* index.